# Remove preference items in iOS Settings Bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, settings.bundle

This is my first time trying to add a Settings.bundle to my app and my XCode version is 4.5. After I added a new Settings.bundle, I clicked on its Root.plist, and I could see there were already 4 items in Preference Items. However while I can add new Preference items I just cannot remove the existing 4. I also tried removing the Preference Items altogether but when I added it back it came with even more preset items.

Does anybody else encounter this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to edit the xml by loading it into a text editor?

Comment: No, I didn't try that, but WrightsCS' answer below does work, so I went that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the item you want to remove and press DELETE.

You also need to make sure you CLEAN BUILD after doing this since there may be residual files left.

Never heard of or experienced items pending to the old / existing plist.